# Get HTML Content without comment lines using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Look at the following code.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <p>sdfsdfsfsf</p>
  <!--<p>testing</p>-->
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert($("div").html());
});
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<p>sdfsdfsfsf</p>
<!--<p>testing</p>-->
```

As I know it will give the output like above only. My Question is, Is there anyway we can get the output without the commented lines?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a clone and then remove all the comments nodes from it(if you don't want to modify the original dom)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $clone = $("div").clone();
    $clone.contents().contents().addBack().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType == Node.COMMENT_NODE;
    }).remove();
    console.log($clone.html());
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6w1nr8km/)

Comment: Very nice approach Arun!

Comment: wow. can you please explain it little more clearly. Because i have modified `$clone.contents().contents().addBack().filter(function () {` to `$clone.contents().filter(function () {`. Still it is working. https://jsfiddle.net/6w1nr8km/4/

Comment: is it realy working? this is from the source code `</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <p>sdfsdfsfsf</p>
    <!--<p>testing</p>-->
</div>
  
</body>


</html>`

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai it is because you have only 1 level of descendants... I just coded to make sure the comments in any descendant level is removed

Comment: @yesitsme that is why I cloned it.... the original element is not modified... so the dom structure remains the same... if you want the dom to be changed, don't clone `var $clone = $("div")`

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6w1nr8km/6/ fails without the 2 levels of contents - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6w1nr8km/7/ - works

Answer (score 0):

try the first selector like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert($("div > p:first").html());
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just an example i have given two lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
use .text() method of jQuery

    <div id="anything">
    <p>Any text here...</p>
    <!--<p>testing</p>-->
</div>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var t=$("#anything").text();
    console.log(t);
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6w1nr8km/2/

Comment: i want content in html format only not a normal text.

Answer (score 0):

Regex works quite fine and efficient for this purpose:

```
$html.html().replace(/<!--.*-->/g, '')
```